# How can I start a Java application from a web server without using a JNLP file?

Tags: java, jnlp

How can I start a Java application from a web server without using a JNLP file?

Comment: please be clear. your question doesn't make any sense

Comment: **Java Network Launch Protocol** is designed for running Java programs launched from a web server. Is there anything you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Why don't you want to use a JNLP file?

Answer (score 0):

You could manually download the files needed and start the app. But why would you want to do what Webstart already does for you?

Or is it a webbased app? Then you might want an Applet.